# C++ and MPI how to write part of code as parallel?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I've been writing some code using PETSc library and now I'm going to change a part of it to be run as parallel. Most of the things what I want to parallelize is matrix initializings and the parts where I generate and calculate a large amount of values. Anyway my problem is following if I run the code with more than 1 core for some reason all parts of the code will be run as many times as how many cores I use.

This is just simple sample code where I tested PETSc and MPI

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    time ( &rawtime );
    string sta = ctime (&rawtime);
    cout << "Solving began..." << endl;

PetscInitialize(&argc, &argv, 0, 0);

  Mat            A;        /* linear system matrix */
  PetscInt       i,j,Ii,J,Istart,Iend,m = 120000,n = 3,its;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;
  PetscBool      flg = PETSC_FALSE;
  PetscScalar    v;
#if defined(PETSC_USE_LOG)
  PetscLogStage  stage;
#endif

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
         Compute the matrix and right-hand-side vector that define
         the linear system, Ax = b.
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  /* 
     Create parallel matrix, specifying only its global dimensions.
     When using MatCreate(), the matrix format can be specified at
     runtime. Also, the parallel partitioning of the matrix is
     determined by PETSc at runtime.

     Performance tuning note:  For problems of substantial size,
     preallocation of matrix memory is crucial for attaining good 
     performance. See the matrix chapter of the users manual for details.
  */
  ierr = MatCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSetSizes(A,PETSC_DECIDE,PETSC_DECIDE,m,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSetFromOptions(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatMPIAIJSetPreallocation(A,5,PETSC_NULL,5,PETSC_NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation(A,5,PETSC_NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSetUp(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /* 
     Currently, all PETSc parallel matrix formats are partitioned by
     contiguous chunks of rows across the processors.  Determine which
     rows of the matrix are locally owned. 
  */
  ierr = MatGetOwnershipRange(A,&Istart,&Iend);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /* 
     Set matrix elements for the 2-D, five-point stencil in parallel.
      - Each processor needs to insert only elements that it owns
        locally (but any non-local elements will be sent to the
        appropriate processor during matrix assembly). 
      - Always specify global rows and columns of matrix entries.

     Note: this uses the less common natural ordering that orders first
     all the unknowns for x = h then for x = 2h etc; Hence you see J = Ii +- n
     instead of J = I +- m as you might expect. The more standard ordering
     would first do all variables for y = h, then y = 2h etc.

   */
PetscMPIInt    rank;        // processor rank
PetscMPIInt    size;        // size of communicator
MPI_Comm_rank(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&size);

cout << "Rank = " << rank << endl;
cout << "Size = " << size << endl;

cout << "Generating 2D-Array" << endl;

double temp2D[120000][3];
 for (Ii=Istart; Ii<Iend; Ii++) { 
    for(J=0; J<n;J++){
      temp2D[Ii][J] = 1;
    }
  }
  cout << "Processor " << rank << " set values : " << Istart << " - " << Iend << " into 2D-Array" << endl;

  v = -1.0;
  for (Ii=Istart; Ii<Iend; Ii++) { 
    for(J=0; J<n;J++){
       MatSetValues(A,1,&Ii,1,&J,&v,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   }
  }
  cout << "Ii = " << Ii << " processor " << rank << " and it owns: " << Istart << " - " << Iend << endl;

  /* 
     Assemble matrix, using the 2-step process:
       MatAssemblyBegin(), MatAssemblyEnd()
     Computations can be done while messages are in transition
     by placing code between these two statements.
  */
  ierr = MatAssemblyBegin(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatAssemblyEnd(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);

    MPI_Finalize();
cout << "No more MPI" << endl;
return 0;

}
```

And my real program has a couple different .cpp files. I initialize MPI in the main program what calls a function in another .cpp file where I did implement same kind of matrix filling but all the cout's what the program does before filling the matrices will be printed as many times as the number of my cores.

I can run my test program as mpiexec -n 4 test and it runs successfully but for some reason I have to run my real program as mpiexec -n 4 ./myprog

Output of my test program is following

```
Solving began...
Solving began...
Solving began...
Solving began...
Rank = 0
Size = 4
Generating 2D-Array
Processor 0 set values : 0 - 30000 into 2D-Array
Rank = 2
Size = 4
Generating 2D-Array
Processor 2 set values : 60000 - 90000 into 2D-Array
Rank = 3
Size = 4
Generating 2D-Array
Processor 3 set values : 90000 - 120000 into 2D-Array
Rank = 1
Size = 4
Generating 2D-Array
Processor 1 set values : 30000 - 60000 into 2D-Array
Ii = 30000 processor 0 and it owns: 0 - 30000
Ii = 90000 processor 2 and it owns: 60000 - 90000
Ii = 120000 processor 3 and it owns: 90000 - 120000
Ii = 60000 processor 1 and it owns: 30000 - 60000
no more MPI
no more MPI
no more MPI
no more MPI
```

Edit after two comments:
So my goal is to run this on small cluster which has 20 nodes and each node has 2 cores. Later on this should be running on super computer so mpi is definitely the way I need to go. I'm currently testing this on two different machines one of them has 1 processor / 4 cores and second has 4 processor / 16 cores.

Answer (score 5):

MPI is an implementation of the SPMD/MPMD model (single program multiple data / multiple programs multiple data). An MPI job consists of concurrently running *processes* that exchange messages between each other in order to cooperate on solving a problem. You cannot run only part of the code in parallel. You can only have parts of the code that do not communicate with each other but still execute concurrently. And you *ought* use `mpirun` or `mpiexec` to start your application in parallel mode.

If you'd like to make only parts of your code parallel and could live with the limitation that you can only run the code on a single machine, then what you need is OpenMP and not MPI. Or you can also use low-level POSIX threads programming as according to the PETSc web site, it supports `pthreads`. And OpenMP is built on top of `pthreads` so using PETSc with OpenMP might be possible.

Comment: So when I'm running my program with mpiexec or mpirun I should do that on our small cluster and in that case the different copies of the program will be assigned to different nodes. After that the nodes just do their own job and return the  parts of the matrix I wanted to form back to the server and it will create the matrix ? I did edit my original so you'll see that I would need to use mpi.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Hristo's answer, MPI is built to run in a distributed fashion, i.e. completely separate processes. They have to be separate, because they are supposed to be on different physical machines. You can run multiple MPI processes on one machine, for example one per core. That's perfectly OK, but MPI does not have any tools to take advantage of that shared memory context. In other words, you cannot have some MPI ranks (processes) do work on a matrix that is owned by another MPI process because you have no way to share the matrix.

When you start x MPI processes you get x copies of the same exact program running. You need code like

```
if (rank == 0)
    do something
else
    do something else
```

to have the different processes do different things. The processes can communicate with each other by send messages, but they all run the same exact binary.
If you don't have the code diverge, then you'll just get x copies of the same program give the same result x times.

Comment: Hopefully I haven't understood the concept too wrong, when you say I can't work on the matrix that is owned by another MPI process I guess this should take care of it: ierr = MatGetOwnershipRange(A,&Istart,&Iend);CHKERRQ(ierr); as far as I'm aware this should give a certain partition for each core ? And can I still test my code by using different cores instead of different nodes ? Or should I just be testing this straight on our cluster ?

Comment: an MPI program needs to be structured completely differently from an OpenMP one for this reason: memory. OpenMP are for shared memory: you have multiple cores that all use the same (share) RAM. MPI is meant for cases where each processor has access to its own memory and CANNOT directly access other processes' memory (distributed memory). This means you have to send messages back and forth. I'm only tangentially familiar with PETSc so I don't know what your particular program will do, though it's possible to write your PETSc code in a distributed fashion.